# Radium hover didn't work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, inline

I'm using Radium to write inline css in React and i have the following error when i want to use "hover":

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null

Did i do something wrong ?

```
import React from 'react';
import Radium from 'radium';

class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var styles = {
            base: {
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                ':hover': {
                    backgroundColor: 'black'
                }
            },
            anchor: {
                color: 'black',
                ':hover': {
                    color: 'white',
                }
            }
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div style={styles.base}>
                    <a style={styles.anchor}>Some text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Header = Radium(Header);
export default Header;
```

In fact, if i didn't use **styles.anchor**, it worked. So i don't understand why it doesn't work with **styles.anchor**.

Another problem, when i try to add the prefix **@Radium** before the **class Header extends React.Component**, i got a compilation's error.

Thank you !

Comment: Hmm I was able to get it work by adding a `key` prop on the second `div` http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/841/ I feel like I do this a lot in my app though and never get such a warning

Comment: You're right. I need a key. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a last question. If i have three anchors with the same style, how can i do ? If i put the same key on them, the problem will happen again.

Comment: use different keys

Answer (score 0):

If you're using babel you have to install `plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` in order for the @Radium to work properly but it's currently deprecated and I doubt it will be coming back anytime soon so I would stick with wrapping your component `export default Radium(Header)`.